# SQLALCHEMY-POSTGRESQL mapping

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two model classes ClassA and ClassB. ClassA has ClassB but NOT inherited. I have a single table with both classA and ClassB attributes. How will I map these models to a single table.

ClassA:
    x int,
    y int

ClassB:
    a string,
    b string

CREATE TABLE TableA (
   x Integer,
   y Integer,
   a String(255),
   b String(255)
)
Please guide me in mapping these model classes to a single table.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Concrete Table Inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=mixing#concrete-table-inheritance) for this.